# JPA Self Referencing Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a Table called User like this:

```
public class User
{
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    //Other fields;
}
```

Now Lets say the User can have other User friends. So how do I create this relationship in JPA.

Meanwhile I was doing this in the User Table in Database:

```
USER_ID 
USERNAME
USER_FRIENDS
```

And in the User Entity like this:

```
public class User
{
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    //Other fields;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(name = "USER_FRIENDS")
    private List<UserEntity> friends;
}
```

This doesn't work. So, how do I achieve this in JPA? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it really OneToMany? Isn't it ManyToMany? And if that, then you would need a junction table.

Comment: Yeah, it could be ManyToMany. But from my understanding, A User can have multiple User Friends. So, it would be OneToMany. So, I am not sure how it is achieved.

Comment: And that user cannot itself be a friend to many others?

Comment: That user can be friend with other users. So, I guess they are ManyToMany like you said.

Comment: Thanks @Florian Schaetz, I think I know what I should do now. Correct me if I am wrong. I will have ManyToMany with adding User whereas I will have JoinTable and set List of Users as friends.

Comment: That's what I would do, yep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing research and help from @Florian Schaetz, I found the solution to the self referencing entities.
The need was User can have other User friends and that User can be friend to other Users. So, what I did was like this:

```
public class User
{
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    //Other fields;
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_FRIENDS", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDING_USER", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", nullable =   false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDED_USER", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<User> friends;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "friends")
    private Collection<User> addUser;
}
```

Hope This will help other people! Thanks again friends!